# You're to stake your pile on Speedy

Tags: phrasal-verbs, idioms-in-context

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XVI, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_16)

Passage 253

> “That is all very proper, Mr. Dodd; there is no wish to coerce you, believe me,” said Fowler; “only, please consider our position. It is really dangerous; we were not the only people to see your schooner off Waimanolo.”
>
> “Mr. Fowler,” I replied, “I was not born yesterday. Will you allow me to express an opinion, in which I may be quite wrong, but to which I am entirely wedded? If the Custom House officers had been coming, they would have been here now. In other words, somebody is working the oracle, and (for a good guess) his name is Fowler.”
>
> Both men laughed loud and long; and being supplied with another bottle of Longhurst's champagne, suffered the captain and myself to leave them without further word.
>
> I gave Nares the correspondence, and he skimmed it through.
>
> “Now, captain,” said I, “I want a fresh mind on this. What does it mean?”
>
> “It's large enough text,” replied the captain. “It means you're to **stake your pile on Speedy**, hand him over all you can, and hold your tongue. I almost wish you hadn't shown it me,” he added wearily. “What with the specie from the wreck and the opium money, it comes to a biggish deal.”

I know what *stake something on something/someone* means but here the word *pile* puzzles me. Does it mean the pile of opium (there are contraband goods to be 'disposed' ashore) or does it have a more general meaning, does *stake one's pile on* have an idiomatic meaning? What do you take *stake your pile on Speedy* to mean there?

Comment: It's not clear whether 'Speedy' is a ship or a person, but I think it refers to money - as in [make one's pile](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sca_esv=580462557&sxsrf=AM9HkKmZqfFTImu4dNAooXJ0uf7qHADI2A:1699452174369&q=make+one%27s+pile&si=ALGXSlbmguQulcNG_yDKi8AKFQVFvuiSboF7I9GQENtmKxLBgK8SlhqfLxg_X_fgo_LvXox52UKfkqodzppB5LzClwqjuLN-c_79-ZrG4wr4pgR38Jf3jqU%3D&expnd=1&biw=1358&bih=620&dpr=1).

Comment: Speedy is a person.

Comment: "Stake your pile" – place (risk) your money.

Comment: It means "put your money/wealth up as a bet", or even more generally "trust everything you have to Speedy", but the precise amount or nature of that wealth isn't important. Maybe if you have been following the story closely you can work out what will be staked, but it's a general message not a dollar amount.

Comment: @ Stuart F - Thank you very much indeed; that's a fine explanation. Erroneously I thought 'pile* would directly refer to the opium found in the wreck, but, as you say, it's a general message not a dollar or an opium amount/pile. I'd like you to write an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pile), usage 4 of 6, meaning 3: *a great amount of money : FORTUNE*.